# How to use JavaScript code in Selenium RC

Tags: javascript, selenium, onclick, selenium-rc

I am trying to find out the Total number of flight details been displayed in a particular search. I used Xpath which works, but not fully. Now I wanted to use JavaScript code from the site.

Please see:

```
a style="color:#FF0099;cursor: pointer;" title="Click here for Flight details"
    onclick="javascript:showDiv(this,'flightdetail28','28','6a7891beb531878bce3246240a2a9e63')
```

Now I just wanted to know how many flights are been displayed, like the above as flightdetail28.

Please suggest: How to use the JavaScript code and implement it in my Selenium RC.

Answer (score 0):

Is flight details in a table if so then use storeXpathCount function in Selenium IDE and provide the xpath like this //table/tbody/tr.

storeXpathCount  //table/tbody/tr   aa 
echo             ${echo}

Comment: @ Atin: It is in Div tag. I am confused to use the JavaScript code.  Also I have used Xpath but it fulfills only 1 requirement, So I require your suggestion in JavaScript.

Comment: Can you please share the full Xpath for the table on which all the Flights are displayed?  I guess you want the count of available flights..right?

Comment: Yes you are right. xpath:.//*[@id='myTbody']  If you want to see the site you can see "http://www.flightnetwork.com" select One way, from: Toronto to Delhi, Date: 10/31/2012, Press Enter. The Result page link should be "http://www.flightnetwork.com/flights/fares". On this page I need to calculate the total number of flights.

Comment: Here is the solution: 


storeXpathCount  //table/tbody[@id='myTbody']/tr[@valign='top']   aa
echo  ${aa}